# Sentry Transport errors

Tags: php, guzzle, sentry

I'm trying to implement Sentry in our application.

I've used `sentry/sdk` but got some errors (probably due to some PHP settings), so I'm now trying to switch the [transport method](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/configuration/transports/).

I removed `sentry/sdk` from my composer.json file and replaced it with `sentry/sentry` and `php-http/guzzle7-adapter`. Please note that in the documentation, they use the `guzzle6-adapter`, but that gave dependency errors (I was already using `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.3"`, so I need to use version 7).

When now trying to initialize Sentry, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Http\Discovery\Exception\DiscoveryFailedException: Could not find resource using any discovery strategy. Find more information at http://docs.php-http.org/en/latest/discovery.html#common-errors - Puli Factory is not available - No valid candidate found using strategy "Http\Discovery\Strategy\CommonClassesStrategy". We tested the following candidates: . - No valid candidate found using strategy "Http\Discovery\Strategy\CommonPsr17ClassesStrategy". We tested the following candidates: Phalcon\Http\Message\StreamFactory, Nyholm\Psr7\Factory\Psr17Factory, Zend\Diactoros\StreamFactory, GuzzleHttp\Psr7\HttpFactory, Http\Factory\Diactoros\StreamFactory, Http\Factory\Guzzle\StreamFactory, Http\Factory\Slim\StreamFactory, Laminas\Diactoros\StreamFactory, Slim\Psr7\Factory\StreamFactory. in vendor/php-http/discovery/src/Exception/DiscoveryFailedException.php:41
```

It is a custom application, so I cannot use e.g. the Sentry Laravel package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs are incorrect at the moment and reference the old dependencies required.

In case that you want to use Guzzle the following should work:

```
composer require sentry/sentry guzzlehttp/guzzle http-interop/http-factory-guzzle
```

This recreates the current SDK metapackage [dependencies](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-php-sdk/blob/f03133b067fdf03fed09ff03daf3f1d68f5f3673/composer.json#L22-L26):

```json
    "require": {
        "sentry/sentry": "^3.1",
        "http-interop/http-factory-guzzle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/http-client": "^4.3|^5.0"
    },
```

Except that `symfony/http-client` was replaced by `guzzlehttp/guzzle`.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Alex Bouma. I did not explcitly include `guzzlehttp/psr7` because it is already required & installed by `guzzlehttp/guzzle`: `"guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.7 || ^2.0",`. I do see the folder in the `vendor` directory as well.

So I wonder whether your suggestion would fix the issue.

Comment: Looking at the `sentry/sdk` package, you might need `http-interop/http-factory-guzzle` instead and the documentation might be outdated, according to the link in the error it could also be `php-http/message`... let me know if any of those 2 work, if so we should make sure the docs get updated!

Comment: `"http-interop/http-factory-guzzle": "^1.0",` has been listed in the `require-dev` secion of `sentry/sentry`. On our production environment, dev dependencies are not included. `"php-http/message": "^1.5",` has been listed in the `require` section and thus loaded on production environment.

Comment: Yeah it's a dev dependency, because in theory you replace the `http-facture-guzzle` with any other compatible factory. Does manually adding `http-interop/http-factory-guzzle` as a dependency to your own project work though? You want to require the same as `sentry/sdk` [requires](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-php-sdk/blob/f03133b067fdf03fed09ff03daf3f1d68f5f3673/composer.json#L23-L25) except for the actual http client (`symfony/http-client`) itself. As a side note, dev dependencies of your dependencies are never installed.

Comment: I've required `http-interop/http-factory-guzzle`, updated `sentry/sentry` from `3.2` to `3.3`, `php-http/message` from  `1.11.0` to `1.11.1` and am not seeing any issues so far. I'm not sure yet whether the "performance" part is working.

Comment: I've updated the answer, and I will work on getting the docs in order at a later point. Off-topic: about performance tracing, just using `sentry/sentry` actually does nothing by itself, this is because it purely implemented in PHP so without a framework integration nothing is "traced" and you will need to add the tracing code to your own code base: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/performance/#custom-instrumentation. You can take a peek at the framework integrations for reference and to get an idea on how it could be implemented.